# JSON string array is always null

Tags: arrays, json

I have some JSON data rendered server-side to be available in the client page. In the HTTP response it looks correct:

```
digitalData = {
    "page": {
        "pageInfo": {
            "geoRegion": "US",
            "onsiteSearchResults": 38,
            "onsiteSearchTerm": "leather",
            "sysEnv": "HAMP"
        },
        "category": {
            "dirID": 2,
            "pageTemplate": "/store/search.aspx",
            "pageType": "Search"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "searchType": "standard",
            "refinementCategory": "10001",
            "searchFilters": ["50859"]
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "profile": {
            "profileInfo": {
                "profileID": "{C0A253A9-AD6E-4B6B-A313-3D215704D0FB}",
                "returningStatus": "new"
            }
        },
        "segment": {
            "persona": ["EXPERT"]
        }
    },
    "cart": {
        "cartID": "2508d65f-6495-4256-8125-75767b847e45",
        "numItems": 0
    },
    "version": "1.0"
};
```

But when I examine the DOM through Dev Tools Elements or Console, the searchFilters string array in the above JSON is always null. I have no client side code that refers to that object at all. How/why is it going from correct in the HTTP Response to null in the DOM? I've validated the JSON in JSONLint and it is valid.

Comment: `digitalData =` is not JSON

Comment: What does examining the DOM have to do with the value of `searchFilters`? All you've posted is an object structure and said it's "wrong".

Comment: In the response you should get the JSON only, without the assignment before and the semicolon after

Comment: There is no JSON in this post...nor is there much of a question that I can decipher...

Comment: Can you post the code that consumes this data into a JsFiddle that duplicates the error.   Right now, there is not enough detail here to identify the problem.

Comment: Seems like I'm getting hammered on semantics. My server-side code renders a <script> tag that defines a JavaScript variable, digitalData, and assigns an object to that variable. I can, thru the console, query any and all elements in that object except for the searchFilters array of strings, which is always null, even though it appears to be correct in the script tag is it appears in the HTTP Response.

Comment: Everything in the code block above appears within a <script> tag in my page. In the HTTP Response it looks just like the code block above with "searchFilters": ["50859"]. But if I examine the page via the Developer Tools Elements tab, that same script tag looks exactly like the code block above except that it contains "searchFilters": null.

Comment: The script includes a variable assignment because it's part of my initial page, not a response to an AJAX call. I render the script with the variable assignment and the data server side to make it available to other JavaScript on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is valid. Append square brackets and try again.

```js
var objArray= [{
 "page": [{
  "pageInfo": [{
   "geoRegion": "US",
   "onsiteSearchResults": 38,
   "onsiteSearchTerm": "leather",
   "sysEnv": "HAMP"
  }],
  "category": [{
   "dirID": 2,
   "pageTemplate": "/store/search.aspx",
   "pageType": "Search"
  }],
  "attributes": [{
   "searchType": "standard",
   "refinementCategory": "10001",
   "searchFilters": ["50859"]
  }]
 }],
 "user": [{
  "profile": {
   "profileInfo": {
    "profileID": "{C0A253A9-AD6E-4B6B-A313-3D215704D0FB}",
    "returningStatus": "new"
   }
  },
  "segment": {
   "persona": ["EXPERT"]
  }
 }],
 "cart": [{
  "cartID": "2508d65f-6495-4256-8125-75767b847e45",
  "numItems": 0
 }],
 "version": "1.0"
}];


function getDetails(){
 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Length of Array = " + objArray.length;
 document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "0th Element of Array = " + objArray[0];
 document.getElementById("elementInfo").innerHTML = "Element at 0th position Array = " + objArray[0].page[0].pageInfo; 
 document.getElementById("elementInfo2").innerHTML = "Element at 00th position Array = " + objArray[0].page[0].pageInfo[0].geoRegion;

}
```

```html
<button onclick=getDetails()> Check </button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="element"></p>
<p id="elementInfo"></p>
<p id="elementInfo2"></p>
```

Comment: My top level object is not an array, so I don't think I need brackets. I have a single object that contains a searchFilters string array, which correctly has the brackets. But object.page.attributes.searchFilters always evaluates to null when evaluated in the browser console, even though it appears correct in the HTTP Response.